# Cannot unsubscribe from eventSource when user logs out

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, unsubscribe

I am using IBM Worklight 6.1.0 and testing on iOS 7 device.

When testing my application and trying to log-out, I'm still subscribed to the eventSource.

This is my code is:

```
function logout() {
    console.log('logout');

    WL.Client.logout('FahrAuthRealm',{onSuccess:function(){
        WL.Client.updateUserInfo();
        console.log('logout Success');

        WL.Client.Push.unsubscribe("myPush", {
            onSuccess: function() {alert("unsubscribe myPush success");},
            onFailure: function() {alert("unsubscribe myPush failed");}
        });
        router.navigate("#home",true);
    }});
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code?
Why can't I unsubscribe from eventSource?

Comment: It'd be better if you mention why do you think you're still logged-in, and whether you see any errors and such in the Xcode console when you log-out...

Answer (score 2):

I think you should probably first unsubscribe and only *then* log out of the realm...
Maybe this will work better:

```
function logout() {
    WL.Client.Push.unsubscribe("myPush", {
        onSuccess: function() {
            alert("unsubscribe myPush success");
            WL.Client.logout("FahrAuthRealm", {
                onSuccess: function() {
                    WL.Client.updateUserInfo();
                    router.navigate("#home",true);
                }
            });
        },
        onFailure: function() {
            alert("unsubscribe myPush failed");
        }
    });
}
```